# dojo contentPane, I post html code with href in my ContentPane. The html code has a script but does not work, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I use dojo 1.9 in my aplication. I post html code with href in my ContentPane. The html code has a script but does not work.

index.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/claro.css">  
  <script>  dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}    </script>   
  <script>
     require(
    ["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/AccordionPane","dijit/form/Button"]
      );
  </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
  <script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;z-index:1" id="main">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'" >
    <img src="ds.png" alt="ds" style="float: left; margin-right: 50px;"> 
    <img src="user.png" alt="ds" style="float: right;  height: 90px;">
    <div style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;">      
        <div id="loginName">    </div>
        <div id="email"></div>      
    </div>      
  </div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'leading'">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #1"> panel #1</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #2"> panel #2</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #3"> panel #3</div>
</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="tab #1" >panel #1</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="tab #2" href="app/view/second.html"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="tab #3" href="app/view/third.html"></div>
</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And app/view/third.html code:

```
<button  type="button"  id="bpru">Click me!</button>

<div id="pp"></div>
<script>    
      on(dom.byId("bpru"), "click", function(){
           domConst.place("<bold>hello!!!</bold>", "pp");
      });

</script>
```

Why don't work the script code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it's chosen to not work that way. With JavaScript you can easily retrieve external content, but scripts are **not** interpreted when you're loading external content.

If you want to do that you have to use the `eval()` function on your content to evaluate the scripts that are on the page. However, this is usually considered a bad practice because if it isn't properly implemented, it may introduce several injection vulnerabilities to your website. Read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/1915448), it covers all reasons why it is considered a bad practice.

If you still want to execute scripts on the remote pages, then use the [`dojox/layout/ContentPane`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/layout/ContentPane.html) module. This module is very similar to `dijit/layout/ContentPane` but it has a property called [`executeScripts`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojox/layout/ContentPane#1_9dojox_layout_ContentPane_executeScripts) that allows you to execute remote scripts.

So your HTML code (**index.html**) may contain something like:

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" title="tab #3" data-dojo-props="href: 'app/view/third.html', executeScripts: true"></div>
```

---

** Small note: I also converted your `href` to a `data-dojo-props` alternative. You don't have to do that but as far as I know the `href` is not a proper attribute for a `<div>` element, so this HTML is more valid.*

Comment: This answer is correct, but I would like to caution that it is almost always a bad idea from a maintenance perspective to use `dojox/layout/ContentPane`.  I would much more highly recommend properly structuring an application as templated widgets all the way down, so that you can properly encapsulate (and organize) JavaScript code within modules.

Comment: Indeed, I also discourage using it because `eval()` is evil, even when it's wrapped inside a widget like `dojo/layout/ContentPane`. Usually when you need something like this your code is not well designed and might need to be reconsidered.

Comment: another +1 for that small note at end :)